# Change Code Color Scheme - Dreamweaver CS6 Mac

Tags: html, css, macos, adobe, dreamweaver

I find the standard color scheme for Adobe Dreamweaver to be aggravatingly bland and worthless. I found a color scheme online that is supposed to imitate the ever popular Monokai code color scheme for Dreamweaver. The download is a .zip file that has a readme file and Colors.xml. From what I've read, this process should be very simple:

1. Make sure Dreamweaver is closed.
2. Go to Dreamweaver's Configuration folder and then into the subfolder of Code Coloring.
3. Rename the original Colors.xml file to something else.
4. Then copy and paste the new Colors.xml file into the folder and you should be good to go...

The problem is that I wasn't good to go because I opened up to see the same bright white color scheme with blue code. I read further that sometimes the above process doesn't work as described and that removing the original file and then replacing it with the color scheme you want will get it to work. However, that didn't work either. Anything I do seems to have no effect on the color scheme... I'm becoming very impatient with this and am curious if anyone on here has any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, you can create a custom theme by going to File > Preferences > Code Coloring. Hopefully that helps and probably faster than importing a theme.

Comment: I would, but there's just so many different options and I just felt it would be innefficient to do it that way. I'll probably end up having to.

Comment: Not sure if CS6 has additional themes, but I'm using the Creative Cloud and there's 5 or so themes on there that are pretty nice. Nonetheless, if you found my answer helpful, feel free to vote up. Thanks!

Comment: I don't use CC. So, I don't have that option. But, nonetheless, I went ahead and bit the bullet and just did it manually. It took a while, but it's done. I'll up-vote you.

Answer (score 0):

In OS X, be sure you're in the CodeColoring folder in ~/Library and NOT in the Dreamweaver folder within Applications. I can't tell from your post if you're in the right place for sure. Try this:

> 1. Ensure Dreamweaver is closed
> 2. Open a new Finder window. Open the ‘Go’ menu at the top and hold down the alt/option key
> 3. The ‘Library’ option in the menu will appear, click it
> 4. Then navigate to Application Support/Adobe/Dreamweaver CS4/en_US/Configuration/CodeColoring
> 5. Rename the file Colors.xml to ‘Colors-backup.xml’ – this is the original colour scheme, required to restore back to default
> 6. Copy file colors.xml downloaded from this site into this location
> 7. Change default background color to #272822 (Dreamweaver –> Preferences –> Code Coloring -> Default Background)

Are you sure you're seeing the exact same theme colors? With the dark DW themes out there, you still need to manually change the background color after starting back up, see #7 above. With a dark theme, all the text would've appeared very light on a white background, but would appear the way the theme intended after changing the bg color yourself.

Themes were just added in CC 2014.1, so they don't apply to you in CS6.